# d3 v4: Tree map is giving NaN for x and y

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have some tree-ish data that I stratify using `d3.stratify`, which gives me what I assume is a proper data structure (it has children, data and parents). However, when I pass it through `d3.tree()`, the x and y values are all NaNs, which makes plotting them impossible. Based on examples I've seen, I don't need to run `d3.hierarchy()` since `stratify` does that for me, and I've tried using `hierarchy()` without success anyway.

I tried doing `JSON.stringify(data)` to paste the data here, but it gave me an error about converting circular structures to JSON not being possible, so that didn't work either. What I do know is that each layer (except for the top one) has a `children` array, a `data` object and a `parent` object, so it all seems to be right.

edit: I tried some test data ([from this link](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd)) and I still get NaNs for x and y. I copied the treeData, put it through `d3.hierarchy` and then put it through this `tree()` call and x and y are still NaN.

```
var treeMap = d3.tree()
                .size(width, height2); // 1020, 170 in my case.

var treeData =
  {
    "name": "Top Level",
    "children": [
      { 
        "name": "Level 2: A",
        "children": [
          { "name": "Son of A" },
          { "name": "Daughter of A" }
        ]
      },
      { "name": "Level 2: B" }
    ]
  };

treeData = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
var nodes = treeMap(treeData); // gives NaN x and y values.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, so simple yet so silly. Instead of passing `([height, width])` I was passing `(height, width)` to the tree function, so of course it failed wildly. Giving it the proper array fixes everything.